# Meteor bootstrap less mixins not working across files

Tags: meteor, less

I am using bootstrap with Meteor, and importing the `bootstrap.less` files, which is installed in the `public` folder, through an `import` command in `main.less`:

```
@import "public/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

Below it, I can start using the bootstrap mixins such as `.clearfix()` and `text-hide()` and they compile fine.

However, when I want to abstract my own `less` code into a separate file `apply.less` and import that file back into `main.less`, which now looks like this:

```
@import "public/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "apply.less";
```

I now gets an error

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/less/apply.less:10:2: Less compiler error: .clearfix is undefined
```

This is really strange. Is this an issue with Meteor?

Another thing I found out - if I put this empty mixin definition

```
.clearfix(){}
```

at the top of my `apply.less` file, things will compile fine again.

Has anyone come across this issue before and figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your second file as `apply.lessimport` and import it as:

```
@import "apply.lessimport";
```

Basically, the less package looks for every file in the directory tree with a ".less" extension and compiles it to CSS individually, regardless of whether the file is being imported by another file.

When it finds a file with a ".lessimport" extension, it adds it to the list of watched files, but does not actually compile or do anything with it.